# Separating Data from one column and distributing to assigned column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to separate data that I copy and pasted from the web that contain a one column with group name in one cell, city/state/zip in another cell below it, and one or more ways to contact (email &/or facebook page &/or twitter account &/or website &/or instagram &/or telephone number), and distance from me. The data appears to follow the same order of entry, but the cell spacing between entries to be separated doesn't appear to be consistent.  I would like to separate the date into columns as follows:

1)Group Name 
2) city/state/zip code 
3) zip code by itself 
4) email (if there is one) 
5) facebook page (if there is one) 
6) website (if there is one) 
7) instagram (if there is one) 
8) telephone number (if there is one)

I don't need distance from me.  (But the distance for the prior entry (to which the distance actually applies) appears right on top of the next entry. It was a little confusing at first.)

Here is a sample of the data:

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like one or both situations:
1. there are no separators so the data is all in one column. A copy paste will do that.
2. the columns are not wide enough and run over one another.

copy and paste into a Word or txt file first and add separators (comma or tab if fields already contain commas). Save file as a csv, or just change txt to csv, then double click it. Excel will open it.